# Como colocar uma @ dentro de {} em MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Ao fazer uma page em MVC5 com Razor, fui colocar o seguinte código

```
   {--conteúdo da @ RenderBody() etc, etc }
```

Gerou um erro porque o @ esta dentro de chaves

ERRO:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character.  Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid at the start of a code block and they must occur immediately following "@" with no space in between.


Source Error: 


Line 74:         &lt;/aside&gt;
Line 75:         &lt;!-- PAINEL PRINCIPAL --&gt;
Line 76: {--conteúdo da @ RenderBody()
Line 77:         &lt;div id=&quot;main&quot;&gt;     
Line 78:             &lt;div id=&quot;ribbon&quot;&gt;

Source File: /Views/Home/padroes_layout.cshtml    Line: 76 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

Como colocar a arroba dentro? e se eu quiser escrever @RenderBody() não tem como?

Comment: Você deseja retornar somente o texto escrito 'RenderBody()' , ou você quer renderizar a pagina ?

Comment: Por favor, dê algum feedback... conseguiu sanar sua dúvida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Alternativa 1**

É só digitar o simbolo duplicado: `@@`.

Isso vai ser transformando em apenas uma `@` no output.

Em suma, correlacionando com sua questão, para escrever `"@RenderBody()"` no output de uma view razor, basta escrever assim:

```
@@RenderBody()
```

**Alternativa 2**

Uma outra opção, que pode vir a ser útil em outros casos, é fazer o razor renderizar um objeto, que pode ser qualquer coisa, inclusive a string `"@RenderBody()"`:

```
@("@RenderBody()")
```

Comment: @Downvoter: poderia explicar o voto negativo? O que há de errado?

Answer (score 2):

**Utilização do (@) no Razor**

*"O caractere especial  @ inicia uma expressão, um bloco com uma única instrução ou várias, por exemplo, podemos  inserir um código Razor diretamente na marcação HTML, utilizando o caractere @ para iniciar um expressão de condição ou apresentar o conteúdo de uma variável." (Alexandre Tadashi Sato, Introdução ao ASP.NET Razor. Disponível <http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg675215.aspx>, acesso em 30 de abril de 2014)*

**Como usar:**

*Declarando e utilizando variáveis*

```
@{
    var texto = "Mostrar um Texto";
    var ativo = false;
}
<p>@texto</p>
```

---

*Com if/else*

```
@if (ativo){
    <div>Está ativo</div>
} else {
    <div>Não está ativo</div>
}
```

---

*Com for*

```
@for(var a = 0; a <= 5; a++) 
{         
   <p>Imprimir número: @a</p> 
}
```

*Com While*

```
@{
 var cont = 0;
}

@while (cont < 100){
      <p>@cont</p>
      cont++;
}
```

**Sobre a Questão**

O [RenderBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorzonebase.renderbody%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) significa que a página vai ser renderizada aqui, ela já tem uma funcionalidade e não vejo a necessidade de imprimir o texto dessa forma, visto que o razor demonstra outras formas como mencionado acima.

*Funciona:*

```
@RenderBody();
```

---

```
@{
   @RenderBody();
}
```

*Não funciona*

```
@{ @@RenderBody(); }
```

---

*Funciona como um texto na tela descaraterizando tal funcionalidade*

```
{@@RenderBody();}
```

---

*Referências*

- [Introdução ao ASP.NET Razor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg675215.aspx)

Comment: Gostaria de saber também quem ta votando contra ...

Comment: Pois é cara, aconteceu o mesmo na minha resposta... alguém votou negativo, sem nem ao menos se explicar.

Comment: Concordo contigo @MiguelAngelo, você tem razão, mas, isso é trivial aqui foi retirado da minha 2 votos entendeu ...